# If found nothing Lest returns "#value"

Tags: excel

Hi i am using Left function to extract some value from a string.
If there is some value present in search string the formula is working fine but if there is noting in "A2" the formula returns "#Value"
What I want that if noting found it should be Space there.

I am using left function as below:

```
=LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1))
```

Comment: you could use sth like this: `=IFERROR(LEFT(A2, SEARCH(" ",A2,1))," ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=iferror(left(A2,search(" ",A2,1)," ")`
should do the trick.
Iferror will save your sanity.